# Struts 2 get result string in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, struts2, ognl

How to get the action result string in JSP?
I want to use the same JSP for all results.

```
public String doSth()
{
    return a ? "ok" : "failed";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

same.jsp:

```
    <%-- 
        Author     : Prabhakar
    --%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>

<html>
    <body>    
          The Result is : <s:property value="a" />
    </body>
</html>
```

ActionClass.java:

```
package com.prabhakar;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.SessionAware;

/**
 *
 * @author Prabhakar
 */
public class ActionClass extends ActionSupport {

    private String a;

    public String getA() {
        return this.a;
    }

    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public String doSth() {
        if (some condition) {
            a = "success";
        } else {
            a = "failed";
        }
        return a;
    }
}
```

struts.xml

```
<struts>
  <package name="somename" extends="struts-default">
  <action name="resultName" method="doSth" class="com.prabhakar.ActionClass">
   <result name="success">same.jsp</result>
    <result name="failed">same.jsp</result>
 </action>
</package>
</struts>
```

Answer (score 1):

Only static access is available

```
<s:property value="@com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext@getContext().getActionInvocation().getResultCode()"/>
```

For this code being able to work you need a configuration

```
<constant name="struts.ognl.allowStaticMethodAccess" value="true" />
```